# How i can integrate spatie/laravel-backup with Postgres DB?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, database-backups

I'm using laravel 5.7 and integrating spatie/laravel-backup with postgresql Database.

Settings of backup.php:

```
`'source' => [
        'files' => [
            'include' => [
                base_path(),
            ],
            'exclude' => [
                base_path('vendor'),
                base_path('node_modules'),
            ],
            'follow_links' => false,
        ],
        'databases' => 'pgsql'
    ],`
```

After run `php artisan backup:run` in terminal I'm getting following error :-

> Starting backup...
>   Backup failed because: Cannot create a dumper for db driver ``. Use `mysql`, `pgsql`, `mongodb` or `sqlite`..

If You need any another snippet of code then let me know.

Comment: is `pgsql` the name you use in `config/database.php` for your connection?

Comment: in both files config/database.php and config/backup.php